# Combining output in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I have a movie recommender system I have been working on and currently it is printing two different sets of output because I have two different types of recommendation engines. Code is like this:

```
while True:
    user_input3 = input('Please enter movie title: ')
    if user_input3 == 'done':
        break
    try:
        print(' ')
        print(get_input_movie(user_input3))
        print(get_input_movie(user_input3, cosine_sim1))
        # print(get_input_movie(user_input3), get_input_movie(user_input3,cosine_sim1))
        print(' ')
    except KeyError or ValueError:
        print('Check your movie title spelling, capitalization and try again.')
        print(' ')
        continue
```

And the example output looks like this.

```
Please enter movie title: Casino

34652       The Under-Gifted
28155             The Plague
12738    The Incredible Hulk
41823      The Ugly Duckling
44976           12 Feet Deep
Name: Title, dtype: object
1177        GoodFellas
1192       Raging Bull
25900    The Big Shave
109        Taxi Driver
7617      Mean Streets
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

How can I make it so it combines the answers? So it looks like this:

```
Please enter movie title: Casino
 
34652       The Under-Gifted
28155             The Plague
12738    The Incredible Hulk
41823      The Ugly Duckling
44976           12 Feet Deep
1177              GoodFellas
1192             Raging Bull
25900          The Big Shave
109              Taxi Driver
7617            Mean Streets
```

Comment: Share the `return` stmt from `get_input_movie(user_input3)`. It looks like tou are sending two series so its printing them separately

Comment: Could you please explain? Or show me what you mean. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return type of `get_input_movie()` is a Pandas DataFrame or a Pandas Series, you can try:

Replace the following 2 lines:

```
print(get_input_movie(user_input3))
print(get_input_movie(user_input3, cosine_sim1))
```

by using [`Series.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) or [`DataFrame.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) as follows:

```
print(get_input_movie(user_input3).append(get_input_movie(user_input3, cosine_sim1)))
```

Here, we appended the results of the 2 function calls before printing it.  The combined results will be printed then.